# How to pass an array of PHP objects as a parameter of a Java/SOAP service?

Tags: java, php, web-services, soap

I'm writing a WS Soap in Java and a client in PHP in parallel. I have to pass an array of "Creator" objects to the webservice. But the more I test, the less I progress. I specify that my knowledge of java is quite limited.

Where I block :

- strings: no problem, it's ok.
- the objects: no problem, it's ok
- arrays of strings : no problem, it's ok.
- arrays of objects : KO

Do I have the right way to write the Java webservice, especially for the `@WebParam` (`@WebParam(name="creator") ArrayList<Creator> creators`) and the `@XMLElement(..., type=Creator.class)` ?

```
    public String createMetadata
    (
        @WebParam(name="identifier")            @XmlElement(name="identifier",          required=true, nillable=true, type=Identifier.class            )   Identifier identifier,
        @WebParam(name="creator")               @XmlElement(name="creator",             required=true, nillable=true, type=Creator.class               )   ArrayList<Creator> creators,
        @WebParam(name="title")                 @XmlElement(name="title",               required=true, nillable=true, type=Title.class                 )   ArrayList<Title> titles,
        @WebParam(name="publicationYear")       @XmlElement(name="publicationYear",     required=true, nillable=true, type=String.class                )   String publicationYear,
        @WebParam(name="publisher")             @XmlElement(name="publisher",           required=true, nillable=true, type=String.class                )   String publisher,
        @WebParam(name="resourceType")          @XmlElement(name="resourceType",        required=true, nillable=true, type=ResourceType.class          )   ResourceType resourceType,
        @WebParam(name="subject")               @XmlElement(name="subject",             required=true, nillable=true,  type=Subject.class               )   ArrayList<Subject> subjects,
        @WebParam(name="contributor")           @XmlElement(name="contributor",         required=true, nillable=true,  type=Contributor.class           )   ArrayList<Contributor> contributors,
        @WebParam(name="date")                  @XmlElement(name="date",                required=true, nillable=true,  type=Date.class                  )   ArrayList<Date> dates,
        @WebParam(name="language")              @XmlElement(name="language",            required=true, nillable=true,  type=String.class                )   String language,
        @WebParam(name="alternateIdentifier")   @XmlElement(name="alternateIdentifier", required=true, nillable=true,  type=AlternateIdentifier.class   )   ArrayList<AlternateIdentifier> alternateIdentifiers,
        @WebParam(name="relatedIdentifier")     @XmlElement(name="relatedIdentifier",   required=true, nillable=true,  type=RelatedIdentifier.class     )   ArrayList<RelatedIdentifier> relatedIdentifiers,
        @WebParam(name="size")                  @XmlElement(name="size",                required=true, nillable=true,  type=String.class                )   ArrayList<String> sizes,
        @WebParam(name="format")                @XmlElement(name="format",              required=true, nillable=true,  type=String.class                )   ArrayList<String> formats,
        @WebParam(name="version")               @XmlElement(name="version",             required=true, nillable=true,  type=String.class                )   String version,
        @WebParam(name="rights")                @XmlElement(name="rights",              required=true, nillable=true,  type=Rights.class                )   ArrayList<Rights> rights,
        @WebParam(name="description")           @XmlElement(name="description",         required=true, nillable=true,  type=Description.class           )   ArrayList<Description> descriptions,
        @WebParam(name="geoLocation")           @XmlElement(name="geoLocation",         required=true, nillable=true,  type=GeoLocation.class           )   ArrayList<GeoLocation> geoLocations,
        @WebParam(name="fundingReference")      @XmlElement(name="fundingReference",    required=true, nillable=true,  type=FundingReference.class      )   ArrayList<FundingReference> fundingReferences
    )
    {
        String result = "";
        
        result += "\n\n===== IDENTIFIER =====\n";
        result += identifier.getIdentifier() + ", " + identifier.getIdentifierType();
                
        result += "\n\n===== CREATORS =====\n";
        for(Creator c: creators)
            result += c.getCreatorName() + "\n";

        result += "\n\n===== PUBLICATION YEAR =====\n";
        result += publicationYear + "\n";
        
        result += "\n\n===== PUBLISHER =====\n";
        result += publisher + "\n";
        
        result += "\n\n===== LANGUAGE =====\n";
        result += language + "\n";
        
        result += "\n\n===== FORMATS =====\n";
        for(String f: formats)
            result += f + "\n";
        
        result += "\n\n===== SIZES =====\n";
        for(String s: sizes)
            result += s + "\n";
        
        result += "\n\n===== VERSION =====\n";
        result += version + "\n";
        
        return result;
    }
```

How can I correctly pass in PHP an array of "Creator" objects to the webservice?

For now, here is what I do in PHP :

```
<?php

    require_once('Entity/AlternateIdentifier.class.php');
    require_once('Entity/Contributor.class.php');
    require_once('Entity/Creator.class.php');
    require_once('Entity/Date.class.php');
    require_once('Entity/Description.class.php');
    require_once('Entity/FundingReference.class.php');
    require_once('Entity/GeoLocation.class.php');
    require_once('Entity/GeoLocationBox.class.php');
    require_once('Entity/GeoLocationPoint.class.php');
    require_once('Entity/GeoLocationPolygon.class.php');
    require_once('Entity/Identifier.class.php');
    require_once('Entity/NameIdentifier.class.php');
    require_once('Entity/RelatedIdentifier.class.php');
    require_once('Entity/ResourceType.class.php');
    require_once('Entity/Right.class.php');
    require_once('Entity/Subject.class.php');
    require_once('Entity/Title.class.php');

    //Configure the options of the soap client
    $options = array(
                        'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE, 
                        'trace' => false, 
                        'exceptions' => true,
                        'stream_context' => stream_context_create ( array( 'ssl' => array( 'cafile' => 'ssl/my_certs_file.crt' ) ) )                                                                            
                    );

    try
    {
        //Create the soap client
        $client = new SoapClient("https://sicpa-interop.inra.fr:31081/SicpaOpenDataWS-rec/SicpaOpenDataWS?wsdl", $options);

        //Prepare the parameters of the request
        $params = array(
                            'identifier'            => getIdentifier(),
                            'creator'               => getCreators(),
                            'title'                 => null,
                            'publicationYear'       => "2014",
                            'publisher'             => "National Research Council of Canada",
                            'resourceType'          => null,
                            'subject'               => null,
                            'contributor'           => null,
                            'date'                  => null,
                            'language'              => "en",
                            'alternateIdentifier'   => null,
                            'relatedIdentifier'     => null,
                            'size'                  => getSizes(),
                            'format'                => getFormats(),
                            'version'               => "4.3",
                            'right'                 => null,
                            'description'           => null,
                            'geoLocation'           => null,
                            'fundingReference'      => null
                        );

        //Call the method
        $reponse = $client->getVersion();

        for ($i=0; $i<10; $i++)
        {
            $reponse = $client->createMetadata($params);

            if( isset($reponse->metadata) )
            {
                var_dump($reponse->metadata);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    catch(SoapFault $sf)
    {
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
    }



    function getCreators()
    {
        $creators = array();
        $creator1 = new Creator();
        $creator2 = new Creator();

        $creator1->setNameType("Personal");
        $creator1->setGivenName("Elizabeth");
        $creator1->setFamilyName("Miller");

        $creator1->setNameType("Organizational");
        $creator2->setOrganizationalName("Ontario Ministry of Natural Resources and Forestry");
        $creator2->setXmlLang("en");

        $creators[] = $creator1;
        $creators[] = $creator2;

        return $creators;
    }

    function getFormats()
    {
        $formats    = array();
        $formats[]  = "application/json";
        $formats[]  = "application/text";
        $formats[]  = "application/xml";

        return $formats;
    }

    function getSizes()
    {
        $sizes      = array();
        $sizes[]    = "4 KB";
        $sizes[]    = "7 MB";
        $sizes[]    = "1 GB";

        return $sizes;
    }

    function getIdentifier()
    {
        return new Identifier("10.5072/example-full", "DOI");
    }

?>
```

And here is the result I get:

```
string(330) "

===== IDENTIFIER =====
10.5072/example-full, DOI

===== CREATORS =====




===== PUBLICATION YEAR =====
2014


===== PUBLISHER =====
National Research Council of Canada


===== LANGUAGE =====
en


===== FORMATS =====
application/json
application/text
application/xml


===== SIZES =====
4 KB
7 MB
1 GB


===== VERSION =====
4.3
"
```

Does anyone have a bright idea to unblock me?

Thank you in advance

Comment: It would really be easier if everyone would agree that comments should be written in English. Always. Every time. Everywhere. You might also want to link to the source of `SoapClient` and [edit] your question with infos like the version of PHP, the soap client lib/pkg itself, etc.

Comment: Sorry, I was a bit rushed on Friday afternoon when I wrote my message and forgot to translate my French comments (which are the norm in my company) into English comments (for SO).